# WPF: How do I get the ContextMenu for a MenuItem in a submenu?

Tags: wpf

I have a ContextMenu defined in the following way:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Add to">
        <MenuItem Header="Test1" Click="ItemClicked" />
        <MenuItem Header="Test2" Click="ItemClicked" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Remove from All" />
</ContextMenu>
```

**But in the ItemClicked function how would I get a reference to the parent ContextMenu??**

For the first level items (e.g. "Remove from All") I can do something like the following:

```
var mi = sender as MenuItem;
if (mi != null)
{
    var cm = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (cm != null)
    {
        var lb = cm.PlacementTarget as ListBox;
        if (lb != null)
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work for submenu MenuItems because their Parent is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [LogicalTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx)`.GetParent()` which will return the Parent Element

```
LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(e.Source as DependencyObject);
```

Comment: This returns null unfortunately; when called on either of e.Source or sender.

Comment: Ah, actually that does work in the simplified example I gave!  In my real case though this is all nested in two levels of DataTemplates so that seems to have messed something up.  Actually in the simplified example I gave even (sender as MenuItem).Parent is correctly set... so it seems I didn't reproduce my problem correctly!